# Python trying to save a unique value in the database

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

Hello everyone What I'm looking it's to generate a random value and insert in the data base, before to do that I'm trying to do it with a list.

The issue is that I need to generate a random code but verify if this value does not exist because it could be possible the random generates a random value that is already in the data base.

Yesterday I just sleep very late but I did not achieve.

Can you guys give a hand?

```
import random
aleatorio = random.randrange(1,9)
print 'numero es igual a: %s' % aleatorio

    lista = [1,2,3,4]
    print lista

    if aleatorio in lista:
        print True


        while True:
            aleatorio = random.randrange(1,9)
            if aleatorio in lista:
                print 'este es el nuevo numero aleatorio %s' % aleatorio
                break

    else:
        print False
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a little confusing compared to your explanation, however here is how I'd adjust it so It matches what you seem to be describing.

```
import random
aleatorio = random.randrange(1,9)
example_database = [1,2,3,4]
while aleatorio in example_database:
    print str(aleatorio) + " is already in database, please trying again"
    aleatorio = random.randrange(1,9)

print("chosen new number: "+str(aleatorio))
example_database.append(aleatorio)
if(set(example_database)==set(range(1,9))):
    print("No new numbers possible within range 1-9")
```

I have had to make a few assumptions such as `lista` is your pretend database. Please ask further if I've misunderstood your description.

Comment: `example_database == range(1, 9)` is a bad test on many levels. For one, it won't work on Python 3 at all (because `list` and `range` objects are never equal). Beyond that, it's order dependent, so it only works if you happen to pick the "random" numbers in ascending order from 5 to 8.

Comment: your right - this something I added so he can see a possible problem. Will implement properly now. cheers.